# Trying to create a function that can find the closest numbers in an array

Tags: python

```
def deze(x,y,z):
    nw = map(lambda q: abs(q-y),x)

    minimum = min(nw)

    anw = []
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        if val == minimum:
            anw.append(i)

    final = []
    for i in an:
        final.append(x[i])

    return final
```

This is what I have written so far as a way to find the closest number but it doesn't seem to work correctly. The formal parameters are as such x is the list, y is the number to find the closest number to, and z is how many numbers in that list are the closest to y.

For example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]=x, 5=y, 3=z.

This should yield [5, 4, 6]

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What is the unexpected result? I see a possible typo: `for i in an:` ... you probably wanted `for i in anw:`.

Comment: there is no error it just gives the wrong output I cant seem to figure out how to first quick sort the list and then look for the closest numbers to x and how many I should find which is z

Comment: What's the output you're getting and how is it wrong? From a quick glance, I don't see anything that would provide the `z` value. Wouldn't you just need to do `final.append(len(anw))` ?

Comment: 0

What should happen ir the list has repentes Numbers?

Comment: What would do if 4 numbers are equally distant from `y` and `z=3`

Comment: the z value is inputted from the tester

Comment: none of those scenarios exist btw in this example

Comment: @whackowarrior They don't but the easy solution isn't going to be robust against those scenarios.  If it's possible to have duplicates in your list, it's important to know.

Comment: well I choose the lists so it won't be lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight modification of your approach.

First sort `x`, ranking elements by how 'close' they are to `y`. Then, enumerate the sorted object, gathering `z` elements, then stopping and returning the gathered items.

```
def nn(x,y,z):
    closest = sorted(x, key=lambda i: abs(i-y))
    ans = []
    for count, item in enumerate(closest):
        if count == z:
            break
        ans.append(item)
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem, but keep in mind if you have duplicates in our list, like 2 `5` for example the you will actually have two numbers 0 digits away (both 5s) and two numbers 1 digit away (4 and 6).  This code would return the lower number of the two.

```
y = 5
z = 3
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def nn(x,y,z):
    d = [(n, abs(n - y)) for n in sorted(x)]
    out = sorted(d, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return [x[0] for x in out[:z]]
```